# Oracle SQL - How to pivote with two tables and compare records

Tags: sql, oracle

I really tried and googled my a*s off.. i found "some" kind of solution but it's still not the perfect solution because i still need excel to finish it.

**Situation**:
We migrate from table1 to a new table (table2) which should store the same data. I want to make sure that all the data from `table1` is 100% the same as in `table2`. table2 also has additional columns which table1 not have and this is fine. Its all about be sure that the ones from table1 are in table2 and comparing them. The **identifier** is `FIELD_0` which are in both tables and are having the same number.

**Problem**: the data comes like this `select * from table1;`
[image: output from query]  

**Goal**: Compare `table1` with `table2` transpose the columns to one column as the first column and then show the record from table1 Vs. table2 --> doesn't matter if they match or not. for that I would like to have a function like `exact` in excel. So it looks then like this: [output goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hMYW.png) 
I tried `minus, union all, joins, pivot` etc. Cant bring it to the view like above.

Comment: Rather than language, Please post some sample data and your expected result.

Comment: Why does FIELD_2 have COMPARISON = FALSE. Look to me like they match exactly - the values shown are the same as for FIELD_10, which has COMPARISON = TRUE. ?????

Comment: I guess because Excel is truncating seconds in datetimes for display. Actual values behind the cells could be "02.05.2022 13:21:00" vs "02.05.2022 13:21:59".

Comment: How are you going to compare two tables in this structure without any row identifier? How to place two rows in table1 against three rows in table2, when there's only one common (matching in full) row?

Comment: Hy all,
sample data is the first image (Problem). There are like 60 columns with different values and types.

FIELD_2: there are just a few seconds difference thats why it show FALSE. Which is great. Here as a Human i know - thats fine and will give the approval OK to FILED_2

Identifier: Sry, forgott that. I have an one- FIELD_0 are in both tables and having the same number. Will add this to the post

Comment: to make it more cleare about FIELD_2 - i have uploaded a new image and changed the minutes to make it more obvious. Also added the identifier as FIELD_0

Comment: To create query with such output you have to convert every field to common data type  for ex. varchar2 or CLOB, because values in column have to be the same type. That comes with 2 problems:
1. Are you sure you can convert it in one to one manner? 
2. String comparison is slow...

To achieve that goal you should use query with `unpivot` for each table, but internally you should create a query with output like: ID (which is field 0), COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_VALUE and the 2 of these result join with `full outer join`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH
    tb_1 AS
        (
            SELECT 
                CAST(123 as VARCHAR2(20)) "F0", 
                CAST(4772119111 as VARCHAR2(20)) "F1",
                CAST('02.05.2022 13:22' as VARCHAR2(20)) "F2",
                CAST('2101968625233' as VARCHAR2(20)) "F3",
                CAST(Nvl(Null, 'NULL') as VARCHAR2(20)) "F4",
                CAST('996013148260662053' as VARCHAR2(20)) "F5",
                CAST(Nvl(Null, 'NULL') as VARCHAR2(20)) "F6",
                CAST(2 as VARCHAR2(20)) "F7",
                CAST(0 as VARCHAR2(20)) "F8",
                CAST('02.05.2022 11:42' as VARCHAR2(20)) "F9",
                CAST('02.05.2022 13:21' as VARCHAR2(20)) "F10",
                CAST(Nvl(Null, 'NULL') as VARCHAR2(20)) "F11",
                CAST('HELLO WORLD' as VARCHAR2(20)) "F12"
            FROM DUAL
        ),
    tb_2 AS
        (
            SELECT 
                CAST(123 as VARCHAR2(20)) "F0", 
                CAST(334651561 as VARCHAR2(20)) "F1",
                CAST('02.05.2022 13:21' as VARCHAR2(20)) "F2",
                CAST('2101968625233' as VARCHAR2(20)) "F3",
                CAST(Nvl(Null, 'NULL') as VARCHAR2(20)) "F4",
                CAST('996013148260662053' as VARCHAR2(20)) "F5",
                CAST(Nvl(Null, 'NULL') as VARCHAR2(20)) "F6",
                CAST(2 as VARCHAR2(20)) "F7",
                CAST(Nvl(Null, 'NULL') as VARCHAR2(20)) "F8",
                CAST('02.05.2022 13:25' as VARCHAR2(20)) "F9",
                CAST('02.05.2022 13:21' as VARCHAR2(20)) "F10",
                CAST(Nvl(Null, 'NULL') as VARCHAR2(20)) "F11",
                CAST('HELLO WORLD' as VARCHAR2(20)) "F12"
            FROM DUAL
        ),
    t1_cols AS
        ( 
            SELECT
                'T1' "TBL", COLS, VALS
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT 
                        *
                    FROM
                        (
                            SELECT
                              *
                            FROM
                              tb_1 
                            PIVOT
                              (
                                Max(F1) "F1", Max(F2) "F2", Max(F3) "F3", Max(F4) "F4", Max(F5) "F5", Max(F6) "F6",
                                Max(F7) "F7", Max(F8) "F8", Max(F9) "F9", Max(F10) "F10", Max(F11) "F11", Max(F12) "F12" FOR F0 IN('123' as F0)
                              )
                        )
                      UNPIVOT
                          (
                              VALS FOR COLS IN(F0_F1, F0_F2, F0_F3, F0_F4, F0_F5, F0_F6,
                                               F0_F7, F0_F8, F0_F9, F0_F10, F0_F11, F0_F12)
                          )
                )
        ),
    t2_cols AS
        (        
            SELECT
                'T2' "TBL", COLS, VALS
            FROM
                (
                        (
                            SELECT
                               *
                            FROM
                              tb_2 
                            PIVOT
                              (
                                Max(F1) "F1", Max(F2) "F2", Max(F3) "F3", Max(F4) "F4", Max(F5) "F5", Max(F6) "F6",
                                Max(F7) "F7", Max(F8) "F8", Max(F9) "F9", Max(F10) "F10", Max(F11) "F11", Max(F12) "F12" FOR F0 IN('123' as F0)
                              )
                        )
                    UNPIVOT
                        (
                            VALS FOR COLS IN(F0_F1, F0_F2, F0_F3, F0_F4, F0_F5, F0_F6,
                                             F0_F7, F0_F8, F0_F9, F0_F10, F0_F11, F0_F12)
                        )
                )
        )
SELECT
      REPLACE(t1.COLS, 'F0_', '') "COLUMNS", 
      t1.VALS "TABLE1_OLD", 
      t2.VALS "TABLE2_NEW",
      CASE WHEN t1.VALS = t2.VALS THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END "COMPARISON"
FROM
    t1_cols t1
INNER JOIN
    t2_cols t2 ON(t2.COLS = t1.COLS)
--
--  R e s u l t
--
--  COLUMNS TABLE1_OLD           TABLE2_NEW           COMPARISON
--  ------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------
--  F1      4772119111           334651561            FALSE      
--  F2      02.05.2022 13:22     02.05.2022 13:21     FALSE      
--  F3      2101968625233        2101968625233        TRUE       
--  F4      NULL                 NULL                 TRUE       
--  F5      996013148260662053   996013148260662053   TRUE       
--  F6      NULL                 NULL                 TRUE       
--  F7      2                    2                    TRUE       
--  F8      0                    NULL                 FALSE      
--  F9      02.05.2022 11:42     02.05.2022 13:25     FALSE      
--  F10     02.05.2022 13:21     02.05.2022 13:21     TRUE       
--  F11     NULL                 NULL                 TRUE       
--  F12     HELLO WORLD          HELLO WORLD          TRUE
```

Here is one way to get the result you asked for. You have to transform the data types to be unique and then do pivoting and unpivoting.
WITH clause for tb_1 and tb_2 are here selected from dual but you should use your own tables/columns/data. And CAST(Nvl(Null, 'NULL') as VARCHAR2(20)) is here for creating dataset. Your code should take care of null values everywhere to get the types correctly. Regards...

**Addition:**
Your code is ok with just a small correction. Here is your code that should work.

```sql
--  OK. Here is the answer with your code. 
--  To make it work with your data you just have to put your 
--  table names (in tb_1 and tb_2 cte-s) instead of dual and uncomment the where clause.
--  You also have to put your column  names where the values are in tb_1 and tb_2 
--  definitions but leave the first selected column as it is ("F0")
--  Basicaly that was the problem - you missed to define a dummy column "F0" as shown 
--  in my answer. It serves as a control column to form and name all the other table columns.
--  Column "F0" is not from table it is just a dummy fixed value named "F0"
--  The rest of cte-s you don't need to change at all
--  
--  Hopefully, this will solve the problem
--
WITH
    tb_1 AS
        (
            SELECT 
                CAST(123 as VarChar2(40)) "F0",
                CAST(101 as VARCHAR2(40)) "CODS_SDR_ID", 
                CAST(11 as VARCHAR2(40)) "CODS_IDENTCODE",
                CAST(nvl(null, 99) as VARCHAR2(40)) "CODS_STATUS_WARNUNG"
            FROM dual ---where F0 = '101100355689650' 
        ),
    tb_2 AS
        (
            SELECT 
                CAST(123 as VarChar2(40)) "F0",
                CAST(202 as VARCHAR2(40)) "CODS_SDR_ID", 
                CAST(11 as VARCHAR2(40)) "CODS_IDENTCODE",
                CAST(nvl(2, 99) as VARCHAR2(40)) "CODS_STATUS_WARNUNG"
            FROM dual --where F0 = '101100355689650'
        ),
    t1_cols AS
        ( 
            SELECT
                'T1' "TBL", COLS, VALS
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT 
                        *
                    FROM
                        (
                            SELECT
                              *
                            FROM
                              tb_1 
                            PIVOT
                              (
                                Max(CODS_SDR_ID) "CODS_SDR_ID", Max(CODS_IDENTCODE) "CODS_IDENTCODE", Max(CODS_STATUS_WARNUNG) "CODS_STATUS_WARNUNG" FOR F0 IN('123' as F0)
                              )
                        )
                      UNPIVOT
                          (
                              VALS FOR COLS IN(F0_CODS_SDR_ID, F0_CODS_IDENTCODE, F0_CODS_STATUS_WARNUNG)
                          )
                )
        ),
    t2_cols AS
        (        
            SELECT
                'T2' "TBL", COLS, VALS
            FROM
                (
                        (
                            SELECT
                               *
                            FROM
                              tb_2 
                            PIVOT
                              (
                                Max(CODS_SDR_ID) "CODS_SDR_ID", Max(CODS_IDENTCODE) "CODS_IDENTCODE", Max(CODS_STATUS_WARNUNG) "CODS_STATUS_WARNUNG" FOR F0 IN('123' as F0)
                              )
                        )
                    UNPIVOT
                        (
                            VALS FOR COLS IN(F0_CODS_SDR_ID, F0_CODS_IDENTCODE, F0_CODS_STATUS_WARNUNG)
                        )
                )
        )
SELECT
      REPLACE(t1.COLS, 'F0_', '') "COLUMNS", 
      t1.VALS "TABLE1_OLD", 
      t2.VALS "TABLE2_NEW",
      CASE WHEN t1.VALS = t2.VALS THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END "COMPARISON"
FROM
    t1_cols t1
INNER JOIN
    t2_cols t2 ON(t2.COLS = t1.COLS)
--  
--  R e s u l t
--
--  COLUMNS                TABLE1_OLD                               TABLE2_NEW                               COMPARISON
--  ---------------------- ---------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------- ----------
--  CODS_SDR_ID            101                                      202                                      FALSE      
--  CODS_IDENTCODE         11                                       11                                       TRUE       
--  CODS_STATUS_WARNUNG    99                                       2                                        FALSE
```

Comment: awesome! thx a lot! i'm adapting it to my envi.
Question: When I query just the tb_1 with my data i receive data (same with tb_2). Could it be that i'm not correctly understand how replace/use the 'T1' or handling NULLs --> which i tried with NVL() see in the code bellow. it gives me nothing. I did it just with a few cols and one record to test

Comment: I don't have your data tables so I can't test it but at first look it seems that you have missmatched column names/aliases in pivot and unpivot clauses. you have in pivot Max(CODS_IDENTCODE) "CODES_IDENTCODE" And in UNPIVOT you are asking FOR COLS IN(CODS_SDR_ID_CODS_IDENTCODE, .......) Result is nothing because there is no column with such a name. If it is possible use a bit shorter column names for there are some restrictions about it. If you provide sample data from table pds_cod_sdr and the other one I will take a look at it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the prefix. Names are ok probably (though too long) but I need some sample data to see what's the problem.

Comment: @d r
OMG! Awesome! The dummy column "F0" was the solution.
Thank you so much for your great work, the fast answers and your effort. Appreciate it !!!!

Comment: You're welcome, any time.